# (RxJava2)Single.blockingGet() don't work on unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2, rx-android

I creating unit test for method of interactor that return Rx Single.
The Single must to return a bean of user asynchronously.
I tried to call blockingGet() for Single but the bean don't return since the test works endlessly. I checked breakpoints and I saw that bean was created but it didn't return.
Also I tried to call test().values().get(0) for Single but it didn't contain the bean. The breakpoints didn't call.

I can to understand what it is problem. I need help for resolve it.

The method in the interactor.

```
    public Single<UserBean> verifyUser() {
    String jwt = getJWTToken();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jwt)) {
        return Single.error(new EmptyJWTException());
    }
    if (!checkConnectionInfo()) {
        return Single.error(new NotNetworkConnectedException());
    }
    return Single.create((SingleOnSubscribe<UserBean>) emitter -> {
        UserBean resultBean = mAuthenticationRepository.verifyUserByJwt(jwt);
        if (resultBean != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(resultBean.getId())) {
            emitter.onSuccess(resultBean);
        } else {
            emitter.onError(new RequestToServerException());
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

The unit test.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationInteractorTest {

@Mock
private Application mApplication;
@Mock
private IAuthenticationRepository mAuthenticationRepository;
@Mock
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
@Mock
private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
@Mock
private NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo;
private AuthenticationInteractor mInteractor;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mInteractor = new AuthenticationInteractor(mAuthenticationRepository, mApplication);
}

@Test
public void verifyUserTest() {
    String jwt = "jwt";
    UserBean userBean = createUserBean();
    when(mApplication.getSharedPreferences(AuthenticationInteractor.SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).thenReturn(mSharedPreferences);
    when(mSharedPreferences.getString(AuthenticationInteractor.TOKEN_KEY, null)).thenReturn(jwt);
    when((ConnectivityManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mConnectivityManager);
    when(mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()).thenReturn(mNetworkInfo);
    when(mNetworkInfo.isConnected()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mAuthenticationRepository.verifyUserByJwt(jwt)).thenReturn(userBean);
    UserBean bean = mInteractor.verifyUser().blockingGet();
    assertEquals(userBean, bean);
}

private UserBean createUserBean() {
    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setMetaId("1539762652616:940c29e6d716:15:jmt4z02l:11182");
    userBean.setJWT("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1hZ2F6b240aWtAeWFuZGV4LnJ1IiwiY3MiOiI1OWEwNDA2MTgzNDAwMDAwIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM5NzYyNjUyLCJhdWQiOiIqLmxvY2FsaG9zdCIsImlzcyI6Im1zLXVzZXJzIn0.2AcuLZjR_-GyWAFen7JczJ5-W37zQWGbnRRErGLqDEY");
    userBean.setId("test@test.test");
    userBean.setType("user");
    userBean.setUserName("test@test.test");
    userBean.setCreated(1535970916310L);
    userBean.setLatestResult("1539676474685");
    userBean.setOnDiet("No");
    return userBean;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not overriding the Schedulers being used. Without doing this you're almost certainly going to get the following error when trying to subscribe using `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread`

> Method getMainLooper in
>   android.os.Looper not mocked

To overcome this you could create a TestRule which allows you to specify the Schedulers for your test, e.g. the following would reset `Schedulers.io` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread` with `Schedulers.trampoline`.

```
public class RxSchedulersRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                RxJavaPlugins.reset();

                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(s -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(s -> Schedulers.trampoline());

                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } finally {
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

To use in your test you would then need to declare the rule

```
@Rule public final RxSchedulersRule schedulersRule = new RxSchedulersRule();
```